# Raster Calc with KendallATS function from "smwrQW" package

Tags: r, raster, subscript, calc, r-raster

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I am trying to use Mann-Kendall trend test on a brick of rasters consisting of 15 layers (time-series of counts) to make three rasters (sen slope, tau-b and p-value). I need to use tau-b and not tau-a, because some of my data are substantially tied and the outputs produced with tau-a (e.g. with the function `kendallTrendTest(x)` from `Envstats` package) are sometimes anomalous (e.g. significant null slopes). The only function I found in R packages and which does exactly what I need is `kendallATS.test(x,y)` within the package `smwrQW` from the [USGS](https://github.com/USGS-R/smwrQW). The problem is that, I can not make this function work with `calc` function from `raster` package, although I removed all NA outside the study area and all the series entirely made of identical values (e.g. `c(0,0,0,0,0)`). I coded the operation differently, but in vain. Here are some examples I used:

```
library(raster)
library(smwrQW)

setwd("C:R/WorkingDirectory/Annual_SCD")
list <- list.files(pattern = "*.tif")
RasterStack <- stack(list)
rb <- brick(RasterStack)

# Remove NA outside study area
j <- calc(rb, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- -999; return(x)}) 

# MK tau-b Slope (PROBLEM)
m <- calc(j, function(x) { y <- 1:15; X <- all(x == x[1]); if (X == FALSE) {
kendallATS.test(c(x[]),y)$estimate[1] } else return(-999)}, forcefun=TRUE)
```

Error message obtained:

```
Error in x@.Data[i, , drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

All the cells within my study area contain numeric data for the 15 layers in the brick. I used `c(x[])` instead of `x` to have a vector, because otherwise, I obtain another error message saying :

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘as.lcens’ for signature
 ‘"matrix", "missing", "missing"’.
```

The `as.lcens` function belongs to `smwrQW`. I have already used `na.rm=TRUE` in both `kendallATS.test` and `calc`, but no change. The function however works perfectly alone with the row and column specified:

```
kendallATS.test(c(rb[250,300]),1:15)
```

My knowledge in coding being very basic, I would appreciate any help to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works, perhaps that can serve as a starting point:

```
library(raster)
library(smwrQW)

b <- brick(ncol=10, nrow=10, nl=15)
b <- setValues(b, matrix(runif(1200), 100, 15))
b[1:5] <- NA

y <- 1:nlayers(b)
f <- function(x) { 
    if (any(is.na(x))) {
        return(c(NA, NA, NA))
    } else if (any(x != x[1])) {
        kendallATS.test(x , y)$estimate 
    } else {
        return(c(NA, NA, NA))
    }
}

m <- calc(b, f)
```

Note below how to edit the function if you want to return a single variable:

```
fp <- function(x) { 
    if (any(is.na(x))) {
        return(NA)
    } else if (any(x != x[1])) {
        kendallATS.test(x , y)$p.value
    } else {
        return(NA)
    }
}

n <- calc(b, fp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked with `kendallATS.test(x,y)$estimate` which produces 3 layers (slope and medians), but for single outputs like  `kendallATS.test(x,y)$p.value`,  I still receive error messages. I marked the question as solved as the most important output (ATS slope) could be produced. If I am not mistaken, P-value is supposed to be the same as with the classical Kendall test and thus can be obtained with other packages, like EnvStats.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution was simple.